# How can I fix python2 console space/backspace issue related with ^H?

Tags: command-line, bash, python, console, input

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10. In python3 console if I hit the backspace key I get to delete a character. That's OK, but in python2 console if I hit the backspace key I get a space character.

**^H** should be interpreted as backspace in my Ubuntu system and it does in almost every place except in python2 console. If I enter to any cli in my system and I hit Ctrl + H the system prints a space, except with python2 console.

How can I fix this behaviour?

EDIT: Seems like the only terminal emulator that doesn't have the issue is gnome-terminal (default Ubuntu solution). This can only be considered a workaroud since I depend on drop-down terminals like guake and tilix. The problem is forcing me to use GNOME Terminal and adjust for it to behave as Guake.

EDIT 2: After I used pip to install pandas package I went back to this problem even in GNOME Terminal. Any idea would be welcome to fix this.

EDIT 3: As a workaround I installed the "a fancy python interpreter" called bpython. At least it allows me to mess around with a python console. It worries me that the problem appears again even inside bpython when I need to use pip (so I will try to use pip outside bpython interpreter). Seems something related with a module called readline since bash and other cli (grass gis) seem unaffected, except when I interface with python inside grass cli.

Comment: How did you install Python 2?

Comment: It was installed by default, using official Ubuntu repos. Most packages I install are from repos, as a matter of factI do not even have local python packages.

Comment: You mean you used `apt` or `apt-get` to install it?

Comment: That is correct. Right after using pip the problem seems to begin, apparently in the terminal emulator used to input this command. I think this page might help (https://web.archive.org/web/20120621035133/http://www.ibb.net/~anne/keyboard/keyboard.html) but I can't wrap my head around it.